# How to Match Two Consitive words if fist one matches

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

How can I match two Constitutive words

Input string

```
fgf     USE  [MarketWorkFlowDb] dfhdjfh
GO use


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM sys.objects 
             WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DeleteLkpDataSp]') 
               AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE   [dbo].[DeleteLkpDataSp]
GO
```

I wanted to match word just after use.
So here Output Should be `USE [MarketWorkFlowDb]`
But it matches

```
 USE 

    IF
```

Also.

I am using `\s*\bUse\b\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_\[\]]+`  to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s` also matches newlines.

You can use:

```
\bUse\b[ \t]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\[\]]+
```

`[ \t]+` will only match 1 or more of space or tab characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lH9mB7/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the word just after `USE` you should use  a matching group, like this:

```
\bUse\b[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_\[\]]+)
```

And as stated before use `\t` to match a white space or a tab character, and use this regex along with `i` modifier in order to match `Use`, `use` and `USE`.

[**This is a Regex DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/sK7sJ9/1).